# Android TurnBased Multiplayer not calling UpdateMatchResult

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am writing a multiplayer game and if I start the app from a desktop icon and another player takes a turn then the game updates correctly via the UpdateMatchResult callback. However, if I don't have the app open and get a notification that a turn has been taken by Google Play Games, then if I respond to that notification and use Google Play Games to take me to the match in my app, then if I take a turn and await an update after another player takes a turn, I continue to get notifications, even though I am actually in the app.

What could be causing this? Ideally, I'd like to see the update in the game, as I do when I go in via the normal icon.

Answer (score 0):

This was a simple coding issue. I have solved this now.

Comment: For future reference, could you say what the issue was?

Comment: The issue was that my code was not handling the UpdateMatch callback correctly in this case.